# In markdown, is there a way to bold multiple punctuation marks (not words/numbers)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am a beginner using jupyter notebook and I'm making personal outlines for python in markdown. There are certain areas where I need to bold the commas (,) because they blend too much into the text.

My problem is similar to the example:

- When I type: `apples, **oranges**, bananas, and **plums**`
- I get/expect: apples, **oranges**, bananas, and **plums**

Which is expected. However, when I try that with punctuation it messes up a little when another bold is needed after the mark and in the same line:

- When I type: `apples, oranges **,** bananas, and **plums**`
- I expect: apples, oranges **,** bananas, and **plums**
- I get: apples, oranges **, bananas, and plums**

I'm not sure why I can't get solitary punctuation marks to be bold without affecting everything up to the next use of bold text.

(edit) The work around with using both, double under score (__) and double asterisk (**) to bold-text two entries, still messes up for three entries or more.

Comment: That may depend on the markdown processor you're using. For example, on Stack Overflow, your input produces the output you expected, as seen in your question. I don't know what Jupyter notebooks use to process Markdown.

Comment: This seems like a bug. You could search the issues for Jupyter notebook and create one if there isn't one already. (I just checked that the same thing happens with Jupyter lab too). What's interesting is that when I have the markdown cell in edit mode, it correctly shows just the comma and the word "plums" as bold, but when I execute the cell, the rendered version is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: This also seems to apply to any single-character which is bolded, not just punctuation.

Comment: @Alessandro 's answer works well enough for now. 

Thanks for the replies :]

As for an intuitive non-html answer, the thought process (correct me if I'm wrong) is that Jupyter should be able to recognize consecutive uses of double asterisk or underscore to signal bold-text. What it seems like, is that it is recognizing symmetrical uses of ** or __ using the first and last instances. (not sure if I said that right.. )

Comment: According to [Babelmarl](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=apples%2C+oranges+**%2C**+bananas%2C+and+**plums**) most implementations (all that Babelmark knows about) get this correct. I suspect that the failure is caused by an overaggressive attempt to observe word boundaries. The idea that some implementations try to enforce is to only recognize strong and emphasis when those tokens are at word boundaries. As punctuation would not be a word boundary, it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook supports HTML formatting

```
apples, oranges <b>,</b> bananas, and <b>plums</b>
```

will get you the desired output.